# Variable does not exist: loginids

Tags: apex, trigger, user

I need some help 
I have the following trigger on the user object, but i am keeping getting a comple error on  at line 16 column 9. the trigger needs to be fired from the User object, when the last login is updated it will update the newly created custom object called  "User_Object__c"

Really looking forward to your help,

This is my trigger,

```
  trigger lastloginDate on User(before update){

//store the user id's that had a lastlogindate change
Set<Id> uids = new Set<Id>();
//store the userid and lastlogindate
Map<Id,Datetime> updatemap = new Map<Id,Datetime>();
//store all the records that need to be updated
List<User_Object__c> tobeupdated = new List<user_Object__c>();

for(User lu : Trigger.new){

User beforeupdate = System.Trigger.oldMap.get(lu.Id);
//check to make sure the lastlogin date was changed
    if(beforeupdate.lastldginDate != lu.lastloginDate){
        //add the user id to the set to be used in the query
        loginids.add(lu.Id);
        //add the user id and the lastlogindate to the updatemape
        updatemap.put(lu.Id,lu.lastloginDate);
    }
    else{
        //last login was not updated
    }

}
//now that you have everything we need find the user object to be updated
for(User_Object__c mo : [select Id,Name__c,LastLogin__c from user_Object__c where Name__c =:uids]){
    //grab the Lastlogindate from the updatemap
    mo.LastLogin__c = updatemap.get(mo.Name__c);
    //add the updated record to the tobeupdated list
    tobeupdated.add(mo);

}

//check to make sure there is at least 1 record to process
if(tobeupdated.size() > 0){
    //update the userobject with the lastlogindate
    update tobeupdated;
}
else{
    //nothing to update
}



}
```

Comment: If it's not a mistake while posting, you don't have a variable called `lofinids`, but `uids` elsewhere

Comment: Such a school boy error, thank you for spotting the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the  `loginids.add(lu.Id); to uids.add(lu.Id)`. You are using loginids variable but it is not defined and for query you are using uids in line 26.

Comment: Such a school boy error, thank you for spotting the mistake

I have added this trigger to the user object, and have got one of my Salesforce users "Michele" to sign into salesforce. The  last login is at 11.47 11/07/14 however on my new custom object "User_Object__c" the field LastLogin__c is still blank , when it should pull the through this value "11.47 11/07/14". 

Any ideas ?